# How do I put 3 equations in two Curly brackets with text

Tags: formatting, brackets

[image: Work around]
[image: Desired result]

So, I have a formula like the one in the picture on the left and I want to make it so that instead of having to put two separate alignments, I can add two curly braces to 3 equations. My final result should look like something on the right but I have not found a way to add curly braces in such a manner. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: I think there are two pictures, top and bottom, right? The bottom one is your output at the moment, right? If yes, please, post the code so we don't need to retype it.

Comment: Given your user name, I'm going to stay as far away from you as I possibly can. You don't need any help, do you?

Comment: @Mico: You're probably right, Dr Faust!

Answer (score 4):

Use two instances of the `aligned` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
a &= b \\
c &= d \\
e &= f
\end{aligned}
\right\} \quad
\begin{aligned}
g &= h \\
i &= j
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: equations]